# Scale background image with changing resolution

Tags: html, css

I made a hotspot login site that has to work for devices with smaller resolutions / screens so my background has to scale with it. Now the problem is that is scales, but it sticks to the top of the screen. So when the resolution gets too small, there is a white void beneath the image. This is what is looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLrHU.jpg

This is my CSS code for the background styling:

```css
background-image: url("img/AngelnträgtGelb.jpg");
height: 100%;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is a media query for screen sizes less than, wherever it breaks and use this for your image size:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-size: auto 100vh;
    background-position: center;
  }
}
```